# Javascript: How to prevent the next line executed until SetInterval loop has been clearinterval?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

Recently I'm working on a project which uses SetInterval and SetTimeout

Here's the simple code:
(Note:functionB,functionC are related to jquery ajax requests)

```
    function functionB() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://MYHOSTNAME',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'XXX',
          'Accept': 'XXX'
        },
        data: MYDATA,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
          var RESPONSEDATA = data;
          //true if match my special string
          var Compare = RESPONSEDATA.indexOf(MYSTRING) > -1;
          if (Compare === true){
              //stop the loop
              clearInterval(loop1);
          }
        }
      });
    }


    function Main(){

      functionA();//can be anything

      var loop1 = setInterval(function () {
         setTimeout(functionB, 1000);
         setTimeout(functionC, 1000);
      }, 3000);

      functionD();//can be anything

      setTimeout(Main, 16000);
    }
   main();
```

I'm trying to make sure functionD will only be executed once loop1 has been ended with clearInterval, it can not be executed when functionB and functionC is still in loop, and only when functionD is executed, the function Main will wait 16000ms and restart again.

I tried a lot of ways with setInterval and setTimeout but no luck.
Any javascript expert knows how to do this?

Comment: `loop1` is out of scope in `functionB`.

Comment: Use a callback to let it signal when it's finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want this:

1. running functionA()
2. running functionB() and functionC() parallel every 4 seconds
3. when stopped running functionB() and functionC() then run functionD once
4. when functionD is finished run Main() with a delay of 16 seconds

Add a alive check for the loop

```
var loop1;

function functionB() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://MYHOSTNAME',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'XXX',
      'Accept': 'XXX'
    },
    data: MYDATA,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
      var RESPONSEDATA = data;
      //true if match my special string
      var Compare = RESPONSEDATA.indexOf(MYSTRING) > -1;
      if (Compare === true){
          //stop the loop
          clearInterval(loop1);
          loop1 = false;
      }
    }
  });
}

function aliveCheckOfLoop(){
  if(loop1){
    addTimeout(aliveCheckOfLoop, 500);
  }else{
    functionD();//can be anything
    setTimeout(Main, 16000);
  }
}

function Main(){

  functionA();//can be anything

  loop1 = setInterval(function () {
     setTimeout(functionB, 1000);
     setTimeout(functionC, 1000);
  }, 3000);

  aliveCheckOfLoop();
}

main();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Nice idea for checking loop :)

Answer (score 0):

A other approach would be to split your main function into parts and call the second part after clearing the loop.

```
var loop1;

function functionB() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://MYHOSTNAME',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'XXX',
      'Accept': 'XXX'
    },
    data: MYDATA,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
      var RESPONSEDATA = data;
      //true if match my special string
      var Compare = RESPONSEDATA.indexOf(MYSTRING) > -1;
      if (Compare === true){
          //stop the loop
          clearInterval(loop1);
          goOn();
      }
    }
  });
}

function goOn(){
  functionD();//can be anything
  setTimeout(Main, 16000);
}

function Main(){
  functionA();//can be anything

  loop1 = setInterval(function () {
     setTimeout(functionB, 1000);
     setTimeout(functionC, 1000);
  }, 3000);
}
main();
```

Comment: your solution alivecheckloop is a better solution when I have multiple ajax requests in SetInterval which might trigger goOn() multiple times at the same time.